# Deallocated object is then reallocated?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to debug an issue where this loop crashes my app

```
for( int i = 0; i < 300; i++ ) {
    NSDate *thisDate = [[NSDate date] dateBySubtractingDays:i];
    NSLog(@"here is the date: %@", thisDate);
    NSLog(@"1. here is the class of objects by day keys %@", [objectsByDayKeys class]);
    [objectsByDayKeys addObject:[[DateFormatterManager sharedManager] yyyyMMddStringFromDate:thisDate]];
    NSLog(@"2. here is the class of objects by day keys %@", [objectsByDayKeys class]);
}
```

I have a repeatable bug that `objectByDayKeys` has been deinstantiated (enabled zombies) that emerges at some point while this for loop runs. The strange thing is that this doesn't always cause a crash (when it does crash it's an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 1` crash). The for loop continues running, sometimes just fine.

Once in a while I get instead of a deallocation error, an error that the array `objectsByDayKeys` is now a string (get an NSString unrecognizedSelector error from `addObject`).

We fixed this by not calling the enclosing method so often (it was called a LOT) and this fixed the problem, but I'm wondering what kind of error this is and how I might be able to do better troubleshooting. I tried Build-and-Analyze, running with exceptions, and enabling zombies, but I'm particularly puzzled about **how an object can be uninstantiated but then back to instantiated?**

Comment: Show the code which manipulates objectsByDayKeys.

Comment: @Apurv This is actually a very complex app, I did not write any of the relevant code and was just trying to debug it, and would not possibly be able to share all code affecting this array. Hence, I'm mostly interested in how an object can be said to be deallocated but then in another subsequent iteration of the for loop apparently not be deallocated.

Comment: Is this in a multithreaded app?  If so, the problem is likely a race condition.  If you have the Xcode 8 beta, you can use the Thread Sanitizer to debug.